# Can we build iOS apps on Windows using flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

Can we build iOS apps on Windows using flutter?
If we use iPhone and connect it with windows using the cable and run a flutter app then will it work, then can we test the application on the iphone?

Comment: No, you need to have access to MacOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no, and yes

You can't build for iOS, without a mac
But you can install virtual box, and install macOS on it, then you'll be able to build for iOS

But that's quite a complex task to do(it was for me, when I tried to do it on my ubuntu), even if you get success with it, it'll consume so much of your computer's resources, and the performance can be poor as well

Personally tried on i5 9th gen, with 4gb graphics, and 8gb ram laptop

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tool Odevio to do that.

To install it, check https://www.odevio.com you can then configure your Apple Developer Account with Odevio : https://odevio-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/6_configure_app_store_connect.html

And then you just have to build and publish your app with a publication build type from the build menu.

[image]

Comment: Does this really works? I'm using Macincloud for years but I want to try something new.